# How do I code my game in python to pause without losing time from my clock?

Tags: python-3.x, game-development, pause

I've tried to save where the clock is at in a .txt file and then reset it to the time in the .txt file but it keeps on going and doesn't reset to what is in the .txt file.

This is the code for how I've been trying to pause it

```
from time import*

with open('prevend.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as prv:
    prv.write(str(120))
with open('prevend.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as prv:
    prevend=int(prv.read())
def pause(end):
    Game = 'pause'
    if Game=='pause':
        with open('prevend.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as prv:
            prevend=int(prv.write(str(end)))
        play=input("To start again type 'start': ")
        if play=='start':
            Game=='play'
            with open('prevend.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as prv:
                prevend=float(prv.read())-time()
end=time()+prevend
while end>time():
    end=end-1
    new = input('Enter "pause" to pause game:')
    new = new.lower()
    if new=='pause':
        pause(end)
```

Comment: This looks like a pure debugging issue. You may want to read "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" and consider paring your code down to a [MCVE].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).